# Index of Maximal Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

My question is about the index of a maximal subgroup of a p-group. If G is a finite p-group and M a maximal subgroup of G, the we know the index of M in G is p.

Do you think the result still holds for infinite p-groups?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you mean in the case that $G$ actually has a maximal subgroup $M$? There are infinite $p$-groups with no maximal subgroups.

Comment: for example, take the additive rationals modulo 1. a subgroup consisting of all fractions whose denominator is a power of a fixed prime, $p$, is a $p$-group without maximal subgroup

Comment: you're right Sam Dittmer, thanks! I meant under the circumstances that a maximal subgroup actually exists.

Comment: the index of the maximal subgroup must be $\infty$ or a power of $p$. can we rule out $\infty$?

Comment: Tarski Monsters have maximal subgroups of order $p$ and infinite index.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks very much! Do you know of any textbook to which I may refer to learn more details about it?